# Вытащить json из html

Tags: php, json, simple-html-dom

Есть html (это лишь небольшой кусок html)

```
<div id="gson_id" class="my_class_json"></div>
    <script>
        var gsonMyText = '{"status":"success"}';
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
               jQuery("#gson_id").jJsonViewer(gsonMyText);
             });
    </script>
</div>
```

Как мне вытащить из огромного html именно json? Хочу его распарсить и дальше с ним работать. Я пробовал через simple_html_dom, но он не захватывается. Пробовал через регулярки

```
$js = "";
    preg_match_all('#<script(.*?)</script>#is', $html, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $value) {
            $js .= $value;
    }
```

Тоже не помогает. Хочу вот чисто json вытащить - {"status":"success"}

Comment: Так попробуйте: `#<script>.*?'({.*?})'.*</script>#isg` и результат в `$matches[1]`

Comment: В итоге у меня получилось, по другому сделал. Но есть другая проблема. Когда я получаю json и декодирую его, то у меня не декодируется русские символы.
Вот нормальная информация в json (русский, который декодирует) - \u0412S\u0415\u041017040
Вот ненормальная информация в json - \u0412S\\u0415\\u041017040.
Как он в первом случае убирает эти лишние  слеши, не понимаю.